# about modular programming in angular

Tags: angularjs, modular

I'm learning Angular and have a problem which I can't haddle.
I use ui-router to impelement jumping from login page to welcome page(includes a directory to jump to the corresponding module). The code is:

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
$stateProvider
    .state('login',{
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'tpls/login.html'
    })
    .state('welcome', {
        url: '/welcome',
        templateUrl: 'tpls/welcome.html',
    });
});
```

now I'd like to add a controller to the welcome template in another file(controller.js), and I created a module for it:

```
var welcomeModule = angular.module("WelcomeModule",[]);
welcomeModule.controller('WelcomeCtrl', function($scope){});
```

I think the welcomeMoudule should be added into the myApp moudule:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','WelcomeModule']);
```

but there is an Error:

```
 [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module optApp due to:
 [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module WelcomeModule due to:
 [$injector:nomod] Module 'WelcomeModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I don't understand why. I've seen a more complicated example using this method and everything's fine. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: What is the sequence of file?

Comment: I finally found that I lost an 's' in the filename...